# Does the PS4 still *beep* when coming out of Rest mode?

Tags: ps4

I mostly ask as a curiosity, since I'm not noticing any other "negative" effects.
Recently I found that my PS4 no longer makes the audible "beep" noise when coming out of Rest mode. I assume this also applies to turning on (I'm just not able to test at the moment).
Don't get me wrong, I'm *definitely* not complaining at all.

I read through the last few update notes (I update pretty regularly) and didn't see anything mentioned. There are other posts online that have the same issue, usually just a broken speaker, which I figure is probably the issue here as well. Doesn't hurt to double check though.
My disc drive has begun acting finicky as well, so I figure I'm just seeing some symptoms of an aging system start to crop up.

Comment: FWIW - I swear it beeped when I booted into safe mode the other day to attempt a "fix" for the drive issue I mention in my question. I'll check later if I remember. That would seem to  indicate some software oddity in how it's interfacing with the controller. I'll probably leave the the current accepted answer as-is though. I'd assume that's the more generally helpful answer in this situation.

Comment: I'll have to pay more attention later, but I don't think mine beeps since I disabled system sounds in the settings. I turned that off to stop it playing the "whoop" noise that happens when you swap tiles on the dashboard etc., Maybe you did that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As of December 2nd 2019, I can confirm the PS4 still beeps when coming out of rest mode. I played my PS4 last night, and it beep when I pressed the power button on my controller to turn it on. I know my PS4 has the latest firmware, since I upgraded the internal hard drive within the last month.

By the sound of it, as you already noted, your PS4 might have a hardware problem. If it's just the speaker, then you shouldn't have to worry too much as far as I can tell. On the contrary, it could more than just a broken speaker.

Recently, I experienced the exact opposite of the issue you describe. For quite some time, my PS4 would randomly beep at unexpected moments (and even occasionally shutoff) while it was in rest mode. After doing some investigation, my research lead me to one of two problems

- Overheating system
- Failing hard drive

With that information, I decided it was time to replaced the hard drive since the internal hard ware had not been upgraded in 5 years. Upon replacing the drive, the PS4 went back to functioning normally and the extra beeping/randomly shutting no longer happened.

Comment: Yeah it sorta happened at the same time my disc drive started to get wonky... hopefully they aren't connected, but time will tell!

Comment: @Belle-Sophie Updated my answer to remove the ambiguity, regardless of location

Answer (score 4):

Based on my a couple of tests with my PS4 Pro (fully up-to-date), it should still make a beeping sound when it wakes up from Rest Mode, regardless of how you wake it up.

Among others, the PS4 Pro will beep in following situations:

- Wake up using controller ("Keep Application Suspended" disabled).
- Wake up using controller while a game is suspended.
- Wake up using power button ("Keep Application Suspended" disabled).
- Wake up using power button while a game is suspended.
- Wake up by putting a disk in the disk tray (PS4 won't take the disk for the first couple of seconds after waking up).
- Put in Rest Mode using power button.
- Eject disk using eject button.
- Pressing eject button while no disk is present (PS4 beeps twice).
- Improper shutdown due to PS4 crashing (PS4 beeps multiple times).

If it doesn't beep for all of the above, your PS4's speaker might be defective.